# Converting string int-tuple to float-tuple

Tags: python

Is this a valid way to convert a string int tuple to a string float tuple, or is there a better way?

```
test = str((1, 1, 0))

# get chars between ()
test = test[test.find("(")+1:test.find(")")]

# if not a float already
if "." not in test:

    str_out = "("

    # add .0 to numbers
    for char in test:
        if char.isdigit():
            str_out += char + ".0"           
        else:
            str_out += char

    str_out += ")"

print(str_out)
```

Comment: This is possibly better asked on stackoverflow. If this is in relation to previous [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131739/problem-executing-string), its not so much a matter of (_needlessly_) converting ints to floats its converting a flat list `(1, 2, 3, 4)` into a nested list  `((1, 2), (3, 4))`  _2x2 for brevity sake_  Btw above will fail with numbers > 9

Comment: Just to clarify, Python questions are okay here *if they directly relate to Blender* (for example in Blender Python scripting, or Python in the Blender Game Engine). *General* Python questions belong over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). BTW, welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't think you need to do that**

Firstly this will convert simple tuples of ints and floats from string

```
>>> x = str((1, 20, 2.0))
>>> 
>>> y = tuple(float(s) for s in x.strip("()").split(","))
>>> print(y)
(1.0, 20.0, 2.0)
```

However if this is in relation to previous [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131739/problem-executing-string), its not so much a matter of (*needlessly*) converting ints to floats its converting a flat list `(1, 2, 3, 4)` into a nested list  `((1, 2), (3, 4))`  *2x2 for brevity sake*

Even if it is a flat list of floats it will throw the error because it wants the members of `constraint_matrix` to be sequences not a float or int.

So without bothering to convert to floats, and having converted string to list (or tuple)

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> tuple(zip(*(x[i::3] for i in range(3))))
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
```

For other methods.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

This is possibly better asked on stackoverflow. Consider using `re` or argument parsing libraries.

Btw code in question will fail with numbers > 9

Comment: I still need to extract that information (x) from a string though, so I could get the tuple from:
from ast import literal_eval
and extract then reform it?
seems to be working :)

Comment: Working example at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131739/problem-executing-string/131950#131950... sorry for creating two posts when one would have done.